# How to make a CSS slider work

Tags: css

I have tried for the life of me to get this darn slider to work on this site I am making and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Once I add in the code for the slider (the news story slider at the top of the page) it seems to be pushing the rest of the site out of wack.

If there are any CSS guys out there that can help. I know its just something small that I am missing but I am at hat point where I cant see it anymore.

The site to look at is http://www.ebusinessmanager.ca/

Comment: That hostname appears to not be registered.

Comment: sorry I must have mis spelt the domain name.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you're referring to.

Comment: The page is opening for me, I just can't see what the problem is.

Comment: scroll down and you will see its not supposed to look like that.

Comment: Why are you developing on a live website!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set the #content-box at width: 100%. Your sidebar has no place left.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, I would say you have an unclosed tag somewhere. The [**W3C Validator check**](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebusinessmanager.ca%2F) seems to confirm this. Try making the page valid first, then see whether there still are any problems.

Comment: I will look at the rest when I get home from work but this looks like it might be the answer. If it is I will check it off as done! Thanks!